# Help identifying encoding scheme for RF device

Tags: rf, encoder, transmitter, decoder, encoding

I have this RF encoder that I am trying to customize with an MCU. The remote control device uses an encoder called HS2260. I believe it is a clone of PT2262 device. I was able to get the waveform but I have trouble understanding what modulation scheme is used. I am planning to write my own code in C for an MCU, I know a bunch of libraries exist for Arduino but couldn't find any C libraries for this.
I new to RF so any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

This is what the waveform looks like. The frequency is 2.68 kHz.

This is what the multiple waveforms look like:
[image]

Comment: Naming it isn't what's important; finding the patterns is.  It looks like the rising edge is consistent, and then the pulse is either high for a short or long time.  Turn that into ones and zeros (doesn't matter if you do it the same way as the original developer or opposite) and then look for repeating patterns.  Figure out what those patterns mean.  You're on the cusp of a great project, but you don't currently have a question which fits the mission of this site.

Comment: It isn't necessarily the naming that I care about, but similar to what you said, I need help with identifying the patterns. I initially thought it was similar to a Manchester encoding scheme and tried to decode it but wasn't very successful at it. Thank you however for the suggestion.

Comment: This cannot be analyzed from what you've posted... especially not since it's a *picture*.  Write code to sort the pulses into short and long and replace them with symbols.  Compare the sequences to find repeating parts; compare the sequences for different commands/functions and see what is similar vs. what is different.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, thank you!

Comment: looks like pulse width modulation, I think there's s special term for it when there are only two widths used

Comment: `modulation` is the way that the RF signal is modified in order to transmit the HIGH and LOW ... the length and sequence of the HIGH and LOW to transmit binary data bits is called `encoding`

Comment: @aeroengineer - Hi, Can you please confirm: (a) Your waveform image was not manipulated to alter the timing in any way (e.g. no pulses removed, inserted, lengthened or shortened)? (b) Following the 25th pulse (i.e. the right side of your existing [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LEuV.png)), there was a long period of "logic low" - at least 10x the duration of the "logic low" which follows a short pulse in the waveform you showed? (c) Did you notice that the 25 pulse pattern repeated at least 4 times, with that long gap between each 25 pulse pattern? Can you add that full waveform? Thanks

Comment: Hi Sam, Thank you for the response. For your questions: a) Yes, I have not altered anything, this is the raw data from my logic analyzer. b) There is, it is about 5.8ms long. I uploaded a new image with the waveforms. c) Not necessarily, I pulled one of the data lines low for a split second and got 3 wave-patterns out. It seems like the encoder outputs as many waveforms as it can as long as one of the data lines is driven.

Comment: @aeroengineer - Hi, Thanks for your update. That was as I hoped, with that long gap between repeats (part of the "sync bit") - apart from yours have a minimum of 3 repeats of the 25-pulse sequence (aka "code word"). The PT2262 datasheet (and my experiments with those) showed 4 repeats of the "code word" to make one "code frame" i.e. minimum transmission sequence (yes, it extends if the /TE signal stays low). That 3 vs. 4 repeats could be a difference with your PT2262-clone. I did more searching a few minutes ago, and found a mention of 3 repeats of the "code word" in some devices.

Comment: @SamGibson that appears to be the case. I am using an RPi to pull the data lines and I couldn't go below 3 pulses. That must be the lower limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoded output from the PT2262 (and clones) has already been documented, including in (at least some versions of) the [PT2262 datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Princeton-Tech-PT2262-S_C42793.pdf).

Each PT2262 input can have 3 possible states - low (0), high (1), or floating (F) and each causes a different pair of pulses on the output:

- 0 = short, short
- 1 = long, long
- F = short, long

A sync bit is a single short pulse followed by a long gap, at the end of the data.

This diagram, taken from page 7 of the datasheet above, shows those three pulse patterns:

---

[image: Address/Data bit waveforms from PT2262 datasheet]

---

You can see that:

- short pulse is 4α "on", 12α "off"
- long pulse is 12α "on", 4α "off"

where "α" is the internal clock cycle length, as set by external components to the encoder.

So your 12 symbol pattern:

[image: encoded data pattern]

is:

`F F 0 0 F F F F 0 1 1 0 [sync]`

for the pin order (at least on a PT2262):

`A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6/D5, A7/D4, A8/D3, A9/D2, A10/D1, A11/D0 [sync]`

There is additional complexity e.g. if the *decoder* is a type which outputs "data bits", then the last 4 or 6 symbols (depending on the decoder) which are sent by the encoder must be either "0" or "1", so that the decoder can output those bits on its data pins - they must not be sent as "F" from the encoder. Also the encoder sends the full sequence (at least) 4 times.

More information is available at a couple of the sites I have bookmarked from previous work on this (I'm sure there are other useful sites too):

[Detect And Zero Rightmost One - Wireless Remote Control PT2272 for Arduino](https://dzrmo.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/remote-control-pt2272-for-android/)

[graznik.de - Reverse Engineering Remote Control Power Sockets - Part 1: Information gathering](http://graznik.de/posts/reverse-engineering-remote-control-power-sockets-info-gathering/)

(That datasheet also seems to have a mistake: It shows a "0" as just a single short pulse on page 9, but correctly shows it as two short pulses on page 7.)

Comment: There's nothing in the captured pattern which stands out as the sort of "sync" you propose or as seen at your links.  Until you see that, you can't actually meaningfully decode this, since you don't know where it starts.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - The "sync" is the single bit at the end. We know that because there is the correct number of pulses (12 symbols = 24 pulses) before that. There would have been a long period without pulses following that last single "sync" pulse. This is shown on page 7 of the datasheet I linked. I acknowledge that the OP's example image doesn't show that long gap after the last data bit, but they might not have realised the relevance of the following gap. I've looked at *lots* of the PT2262 waveforms. The OP even says it's from a PT2262 clone, so I don't see why you say it can't be decoded??

Comment: @ChrisStratton - "*you don't know where it starts*" If it helps, yes, we do know where that pattern starts, if we believe that the OP has given an accurate waveform image. There will always be a long gap following the full 25 pulse (12 "bit" + sync) address/data sequence, since the final sync bit is a 4 alpha "on", then 124 alpha "off", making such a long gap (the "off" state) obvious on any waveform image. The OP's waveform doesn't show that long "off", meaning that the sync bit didn't occur *during* the sequence shown - thus confirming it's that 25th pulse at the end. See what I mean?

Comment: That's making a *lot* of assumptions that the gap is precisely the part that is missing, no more, no less.  Maybe it's right, maybe it isn't and this is some extended version different from your document.  Any practical attempt would have to see the gap to sync with it regardless, since it doesn't have a human to trim the recording.  The nice part is that with the gap, you don't actually have to know *anything* about the target system, you can just compare patterns to their purpose/effect such that you can do this for undocumented schemes and not just (possibly) documented ones.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - "*That's making a lot of assumptions*" I respectfully disagree - it's exactly *one* assumption, and knowing the PT2262 waveforms very well, it's one that I've seen done before. That gap is such an obvious "end of data" signal, once you've seen enough of those waveforms. I have commented to the OP requesting that they confirm that there is a gap there, to remove any doubts.

Comment: The gap is only "obvious" if it's actually present where you hope it is.  The key fact remains: a decoder has to key on the gap, and without the gap, it can't function.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - "*The key fact remains: a decoder has to key on the gap, and without the gap, it can't function.*" Exactly! And since this trace is from an existing PT2262-type encoder, the gap exists *somewhere*. So if we believe that the OP hasn't manipulated the waveform image (which seems to come from an LA GUI), and I see no implication that they have, and I agree the gap must be there for the decoder to function as you say, then the gap must have been missed from the trace - so a gap must follow the waveform already given, as that's the only part missing. I've asked the OP to confirm.

Comment: Hi @SamGibson, thank you; I think you cracked that encoding scheme perfectly, I just tested all the pins of the encoder and they match exactly with what you have pointed me to. What would you say is the best way to create a decoder for this? I know specialized decoders do exists but it seems like putting a code into a low-power MCU would be more robust.

Comment: Naively you could trigger on each rising edge and delay enough to sample the pulse where a long will still be high and a short will be low again.  Trigger it all off an inter-pulse gap long enough to be a sync gap.  But that potentially discards information; ultimately you'd need an AGC and ideally the AGC and possible subsequent discernment in software could leverage knowledge of what the valid possibilities for the signal are.  If there's no checksum you might have to wait until you get a few matching repeats...  If you look you'll probably find existing Arduino or similar code.

Comment: @aeroengineer - *Chris Stratton* has already kindly commented a simple approach. As he & I was discussing above, that inter-code word "sync gap" (or the equivalent gap before the first transmission) allows a receiver to detect that it is *not* starting to receive in the middle of a code word transmission. A common Arduino library used to transmit & receive PT2262/PT2272 and similar codes, and which could give you other ideas, is the [RC Switch library](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch). I believe PT2262 is "protocol 1" setting in that library - use its receiver example code to confirm.

Comment: @aeroengineer - Just FYI, note that the RC Switch library and documentation uses its own terminology for describing the pulse lengths, which is different from the PT2262 datasheet e.g. it uses a pulse length of 1 to mean the shortest length pulse e.g. the length of the first pulse for a logic 0 (i.e. 4α) and a pulse length of 3 to mean the length of the first pulse for a logic 1 (i.e. 12α).

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton and SamGibson, thank you both. I have been utilizing the RC Switch library. I am going to try to figure out how to write my own software to do this. Thank you both, this gave me a lot of insight.